# Issues with pulse audio, it dosn't show analog output

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

So a short story:

To join zoom meetings, I use a vm, but there was lag with the mic between the host and guest (5 - 10 seconds), after some research, seems switching the host driver to Alsa is the key. After doing that I only get audio from the host on the right channel, left is silent, putting it back to pulse didn't work. So I decide to reinstall both Alsa and pulse, turns out that caused some problems.

Alsa, while it can't really interface with apps, I can at least see my built in analog out, but when installing PulseAudio with it, I only see my analog in, no matter what I do. Please help, this is... way to stressing.

Comment: You did lots of things, so it's difficult to spot what went wrong. In general, if there's an application that already uses an output when you startup Pulseaudio, then Pulseaudio won't be able to claim it, so you won't see it in Pulseaudio. So I guess that's somehow what happened. But it's impossible to debug with the information you have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a program called pipewire that was getting control of my soundcard before pulseaudio could